# Scroll a ImageView on scroll of the RecyclerView

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, scrollview

My requirement is scrolling a `ImageView` left and right on top of a list of data in the `Recyclerview`. When `Recyclerview` is scrolled up the `ImageView` will move towards right until list reaches to the end and vice versa.

I have tried but facing few complexity any suggestions and reference will be  very helpful.Or any logic will also be appreciated.

The problem what I facing now is that not able to handle the values in the **addOnScrollListener**

Sharing my code in the github: [Github Link](https://github.com/avik1990/ScrollImageView)

**MainActivity Code:**
Sharing few lines of code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, ClickEventLisener {

        HorizontalScrollView v_scroll;
        Button btn_left, btn_right;
        int pos = 0;
        int temppos = 0;
        int initialpos = 0;
        RecyclerView rv_recycler;
        UserApapter adapter;
        List<Users> user = new ArrayList<>();
        Context mContext;
        boolean isFirsttime = true;
        ImageView iv_image;
        String imageurl = "https://www.isometrix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/featured-images-about.jpg";
        int screenwidth = 0, imagewidth = 0;
        int scroolby_val = 0;

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mContext = this;

            iv_image = findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            v_scroll = findViewById(R.id.v_scroll);
            btn_left = findViewById(R.id.btn_left);
            btn_right = findViewById(R.id.btn_right);
            rv_recycler = findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler);
            btn_left.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn_right.setOnClickListener(this);

            v_scroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            filllist();
            getScreenSize();
            setupimage();
            getleftscroll();
            // when scrolled to the leftmost position the variables are initialized
            v_scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
                    initialpos = i;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        temppos = 0;
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });

            ///not able to understand how to handle the values
            //handling the scroll
            rv_recycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    getleftscroll();
                    if (dy > 0) {
                        temppos = temppos + scroolby_val;
                        v_scroll.scrollTo(temppos, 0);
                        Log.d("Scroll", "ScrollUp");
                        Log.d("temppos", "" + temppos);
                    } else {
                        if (initialpos != 0) {
                            temppos = temppos - scroolby_val;
                            v_scroll.scrollTo(temppos, 0);
                            Log.d("temppos1", "" + temppos);
                            Log.d("Scroll", "ScrollDown");
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                        // Do something
                    } else if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        // Do something
                    } else {
                        // Do something
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        private void getScreenSize() {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            Log.d("ScreenWidth", "" + width);
            screenwidth = width;
        }

        private void setupimage() {
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(imageurl)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                            int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                            Log.d("ImageWitdh", "" + w);
                            iv_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            imagewidth = w;
                        }
                    });


        }

/*
    Logic I have implemented:calculated Imagewidth and screenwidth. Then minus it (imagewidth > screenwidth) and then divide it by the number of values in the array.
    if the value is 0 then scrolling it by 1 per scroll or if the returned value is 3 then scrolling it by 3. 
    IOS team have done this way and working good for them but I am facing a minor issue here.
*/
        private void getleftscroll() {
            imagewidth = 2000;
            if (imagewidth > screenwidth) {
                int leftoutscreen = imagewidth - screenwidth;
                scroolby_val = leftoutscreen / user.size();
                if (scroolby_val == 0) {
                    scroolby_val = 1;
                }
                // temppos = 0;
                Log.d("scroolby_val", "" + scroolby_val);
            }

        }


        ///button is just for demo purpose///
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == btn_left) {
                if (initialpos != 0) {
                    temppos = temppos - pos--;
                    v_scroll.scrollTo(temppos, 0);
                    Log.d("temppos", "" + temppos);
                }
            } else if (v == btn_right) {
                temppos = temppos + pos++;
                v_scroll.scrollTo(temppos, -temppos);
                Log.d("temppos", "" + temppos);
            }
        }


        private void filllist() {
            user.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
                user.add(new Users(String.valueOf(i + 1), "name " + i));
            }
            inflateadapter();
        }

        private void inflateadapter() {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            adapter = new UserApapter(this, R.layout.row_users, user, this);
            rv_recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            rv_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        @Override
        public void Currentposition(int position) {
            Log.d("Currentposition", "" + position);
            if (position == user.size() - 1) {
                if (scroolby_val == 1) {
                    Log.d("scroolby_val", "" + scroolby_val);
                    Log.d("Inside", "Inside");
                    // v_scroll.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    // temppos = 1;
                }
            } else if (position == 0) {
                temppos = 0;
            }
            pos = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void ClickEventLisener(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I run your code. Do you want to distribute movement of image on the basis of number of items in list? how you want from image to move? Details will be appreciated.

Comment: yes you r right it depends on the number of items in the list

Comment: means that the image started moving with scrolling of first item of list and scrolled to right most with movement of last item of list? Tell me if i am wrong.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: ok thanks for details.

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmedKhan are u looking into it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178918/discussion-between-muhammad-zahab-ahmed-khan-and-avik).

Answer (score 0):

Few things you may want to consider-

1. Don't use dy values from onScrolled callback directly to set scroll of v_scroll. There should be a logic to map scroll state of recycler view to the required scroll in v_scroll.
2. Don't use dy at all. Logic to set scroll of v_scroll should be based on the number of items in the list and the first/last visible child in it. (RecyclerView provides methods to get that.) You can run that logic from onScrolled callback.

Comment: i think it can not be achieved only taking array size into account.Image width is also important for achieving this.